# Why rebuilding when TextField tapped?

Tags: flutter

If remove the MediaQuery.of(context).size code, it will not rebuild.

this is my code.

```
class ExamplePage extends StatelessWidget {
    Future<Size> init(BuildContext context) async {
    print("init");
    return MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    }

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: FutureBuilder(
            future: init(context),
            builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<Size> snapshot) {
                return Center(child: TextField());
            }));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
future: init(context),
```

This will probably cause init(context) to be called each time build() is called for this widget.  Instead, something like this should be done in the initState() for this widget, so that it is done only once at widget creation.